# How do you make a custom renderer for iOS DatePicker Xamarin

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin

I currently want to build a DatePicker with custom buttons on iOS using Xamarin. Out of the box there doesn't seem to be way to do.

Would anyone know how to build a custom renderer that would allow me to add a Cancel button and Next Button when the DatePickerDialog comes into focus?

I basically want this but at the top of this a Cancel button on the left and a next button on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to piece together a solution that does exactly what I want. Unfortunately, I had to use objectveC techniques mixed in with c# in order to get it to work. There is currently a issue triaged in the Xamarin project.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14156

For now here is my solution, which I hope helps others with their similar problems

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using dcbel.Mobile.Controls;
using dcbel.Mobile.iOS.Extensions;
using dcbel.Mobile.iOS.Renderers;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomDatePicker), typeof(CustomDatePickerRenderer))]

namespace dcbel.Mobile.iOS.Renderers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An extended date picker renderer.
    /// </summary>
    ///
    /// <seealso cref="T:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.DatePickerRenderer"/>
    public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the element property changed action.
        /// </summary>
        ///
        /// <param name="sender"> Source of the event. </param>
        /// <param name="e">      A PropertyChangedEventArgs? to process. </param>
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs? e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e != null && e.PropertyName == "DateTime" && this.Element is CustomDatePicker datePicker)
            {
                this.Control.Text = datePicker.DateTime.ToString(datePicker.Format, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the element changed action.
        /// </summary>
        ///
        /// <param name="e"> An ElementChangedEventArgs{DatePicker} to process. </param>
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.Control != null && e?.NewElement is CustomDatePicker datePicker)
            {
                this.Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;

                if (this.Control.InputAccessoryView is UIToolbar toolbar)
                {
                    var buttonTextAttributes = new UITextAttributes()
                    {
                        Font = UIFont.FromName("SFStrong", 15),
                        TextColor = UIColorExtensions.FromHex("5A5E62"),
                    };

                    using var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(datePicker.DoneButtonText, UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, this, ObjCRuntime.Selector.FromHandle(ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle("DoneButtonAction:")));
                    using var cancelButton = new UIBarButtonItem(datePicker.CancelButtonText, UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, this, ObjCRuntime.Selector.FromHandle(ObjCRuntime.Selector.GetHandle("CancelButtonAction:")));
                    using var title = new UIBarButtonItem(datePicker.TitleText, UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null) { Enabled = false };
                    using var space = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace);

                    doneButton.SetTitleTextAttributes(buttonTextAttributes, UIControlState.Normal);
                    title.SetTitleTextAttributes(buttonTextAttributes, UIControlState.Normal);
                    title.SetTitleTextAttributes(buttonTextAttributes, UIControlState.Disabled);
                    cancelButton.SetTitleTextAttributes(buttonTextAttributes, UIControlState.Normal);
                    toolbar.SetItems(new UIBarButtonItem[] { cancelButton, space, title, space, doneButton }, true);
                }

                if (this.Control.InputView is UIDatePicker uiDatePicker)
                {
                    uiDatePicker.Mode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime;
                }
            }
        }

        [Action("CancelButtonAction:")]
        private void CancelButtonAction(NSObject sender)
        {
            this.Control.ResignFirstResponder();
            this.Element.Unfocus();
        }

        [Action("DoneButtonAction:")]
        private void DoneButtonAction(NSObject sender)
        {
            var barButton = (UIBarButtonItem)sender;
            if (barButton.Target is CustomDatePickerRenderer datePickerRenderer)
            {
                if (datePickerRenderer.Control?.InputView is UIDatePicker uiDatePicker)
                {
                    var dateSelected = uiDatePicker.Date.ToDateTime();
                    ((CustomDatePicker)this.Element).DateTime = dateSelected;
                }
            }

            this.Control.ResignFirstResponder();
            this.Element.Unfocus();
        }
    }
}
```